# Eclipse - File is empty after crash

Tags: android, eclipse, file, crash

My computer freezed and i had to shut him down by holding the start button. After rebooting I started eclipse, I opened the last project I worked on when the pc crashed and the main source file is empty. All other files are ok and I have the app saved on my phone and dropbox. How can i restore the source file?

thanks thomas

Comment: Try right clicking on the file and choosing `Replace with > Local History`.

Comment: Another no-backupper...

Comment: thank you, you saved my day and the work of more than a week :D

Comment: @greg-449 - please repost as an *answer* so that this question can be correctly resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the file and choose `Replace with > Local History`. Eclipse should have several versions of the file available (although it may not have the very latest).

You can configure how much history Eclipse keeps in `Preferences > General > Workspace > Local History`

It may also be worth using a source control system like Git or SVN even if you don't share code with anyone just for the additional backup.